# Call Php when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this button:

```
<input type = "button" name = "btn_sample" value = "click me" />
```

And also have this php function on the upper part of my page:

```
<?php
   function php_click(){
      echo "Hello!";
   }
?>
```

I want to link the button to the php function which calls the function everytime the button is pressed. Is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: As PHP runs on the server and JS on the client, you'll need to make a request to the server to do what you need. To do that you can either submit a form, or make an AJAX request. Although, making a server request just to output 'Hello!' to the page seems quite redundant.

Comment: search for: ajax request

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! This basically solves the problem!